# Is possible to set default type for enum to be unsigned char?

Tags: c++

I have to pack some enumerations to byte array (`char*`) and send over network. Is possible to set default type for enum to be unsigned char? (I can now cast or use `& 0xff` to extract first byte/char but that requires additional operations so is there any way to solve this at definition of enum?)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is only possible with C++11 [strongly typed enums](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Strongly_typed_enumerations):

```
enum class MyEnum : unsigned char { E1, E2 };
```

See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum) for more information

Comment: Strongly-typed enum by itself is not needed, C++11 allows to specify the default type for regular enums too.